# JSON not print as Pretty Print using GSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala, gson

My code is as below :

```
 var json_val = (Json(DefaultFormats).write(map))
```

The above json value is like as below :

```
{"Tatyana Nader":[{"source":"Marseille Rail Station (XRF)","amount":"5000.0","points":"500","date_time":"Sun Dec 06 07:36:09 IST 2015","class":"First","destination":"Batna Arpt (BLJ)"}]}
```

I want to print this json data as beautify JSON / Preety Json.

So I have used gson for that as below :

```
var gson:Gson = null
gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create()
var jp: JsonParser = null
var je: JsonElement = null
je = jp.parse(json_val)
var json: String = gson.toJson(json_val)
var prettyJsonString: String = gson.toJson(je)
```

I have tried lot's of time but it's returning Null Pointer Exception every time.
Please advice on it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the code you provided, you create a mutable variable `jp` initialised as `null`, but nothing gets placed there. When you attempt to use the variable `jp`, you get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `Play Json`

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

val jsonString = """{"Tatyana Nader":[{"source":"Marseille Rail Station (XRF)","amount":"5000.0","points":"500","date_time":"Sun Dec 06 07:36:09 IST 2015","class":"First","destination":"Batna Arpt (BLJ)"}]}"""

Json.prettyPrint(Json.parse(jsonString)).toString
```